# Correct date format for publication date youtube api

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, symfony

Getting the following error when I try to put the date in the follwing format:

```
date_format(date_create($this->output->publication_date), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

> "Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-14 00:00:00\" is
>   malformed at \" 00:00:00\"

[image: "Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-14 00:00:00\" is malformed at \" 00:00:00\"]

What is the correct format that is needed to set the publication date when uploading a video to youtube?

According to the [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) the format should be

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ
```

How to do this correctly in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ISO 8601 format, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the correct selector.

As example, you can use it in your code as follow:

```
$date = date_create($this->output->publication_date);
$formatted = $date->format('c');
```

or

```
date_format(date_create($this->output->publication_date), 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z');
```

hope this help